# Assertion Error - Junit testcase

Tags: junit, mockito, assertion

I have the following method to which I want to test using JUnuit and Mockito.

```
public Map<String, String> getUserACLDetails(final int userId, final int networkId, final List<String> privilegeNames) 
{
    final Map<String, String> privilegeNameValue = new HashMap<>();
    final Object aclDataString = cbClient.get(String.valueOf(userId));
    Map<String, String> aclData = null;

    if (null != aclDataString && !aclDataString.equals(NULL)) 
    {
        aclData = gson.fromJson(aclDataString.toString(), new HashMap<String, String>().getClass());
    }

    for (String privilegeName : privilegeNames) 
    {
        String innerMapKey = String.valueOf(networkId) + UNDER_SCORE + privilegeName;

        if (aclData.containsKey(innerMapKey)) 
        {
            privilegeNameValue.put(privilegeName, aclData.get(innerMapKey));
        }
    }
    return privilegeNameValue;
}
```

Following is the testcase -

```
 public void getUserACLDetailsWithReturnValueTest() 
 {
    final int userId = 123;
    final int networkId = 525;
    List<String> privilegeNames = new ArrayList<>();
    String privilegeName = "PRIVILEGE_ACCESS_VIEW";
    String privilegeValue = "true";
    privilegeNames.add(privilegeName);
    Map<String, String> privilegeNameValues = new HashMap<>();
    privilegeNameValues.put(privilegeName,privilegeValue);
    Map<String, String> aclData = new HashMap<>();
    aclData.put(String.valueOf(networkId) + "_" + privilegeName, privilegeValue);
    privilegeName = "PRIVILEGE_ACCESS_EDIT";
    privilegeValue = "false";
    aclData.put(String.valueOf(networkId) + "_" + privilegeName, privilegeValue);
    Mockito.when(couchbaseClient.get(String.valueOf(userId))).thenReturn(aclData);
    assertEquals(privilegeNameValues, userAclDao.getUserACLDetails(userId, networkId, privilegeNames));
}
```

But when I execute the testcase I get the following error -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.HashMap<{PRIVILEGE_CREATIVE_ACCESS_VIEW=true}> but was: java.util.HashMap<{PRIVILEGE_CREATIVE_ACCESS_VIEW=true}>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
at com.zedo.nirvana.hriday.authorization.UserAclDaoCouchbaseImplTest.getUserACLDetailsWithReturnValueTest(UserAclDaoCouchbaseImplTest.java:153)
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong here. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the correct testcase -

```
 public void getUserACLDetailsWithReturnValueTest() {
    final int userId = 123;
    final int networkId = 525;
    List<String> privilegeNames = new ArrayList<>();
    String privilegeName = "PRIVILEGE_CREATIVE_ACCESS_VIEW";
    String privilegeValue = "true";
    privilegeNames.add(privilegeName);
    final Object aclDataString = "{\"525" + "_" + privilegeName + "\": \"" + privilegeValue + "\"}";
    Map<String, String> privilegeNameValues = new HashMap<>();
    privilegeNameValues.put(privilegeName, privilegeValue);
    Mockito.when(couchbaseClient.get(String.valueOf(userId))).thenReturn(aclDataString);
    assertEquals(privilegeNameValues, userAclDao.getUserACLDetails(userId, networkId, privilegeNames));
}
```

I had made a mistake while returning the value when the mocked objects method was called.